# Fast hyperbolic tangent approximation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, math, approximation

I'm doing some digital signal processing calculations in javascript, and I found that calculating the hyperbolic tangent (**tanh**) is a bit too expensive. This is how I currently approximate **tanh**:

```
function tanh (arg) {
    // sinh(number)/cosh(number)
    return (Math.exp(arg) - Math.exp(-arg)) / (Math.exp(arg) + Math.exp(-arg));
}
```

Anyone knows a faster way to calculate it?

Comment: you need to specify two key pieces of information (a) what's the domain of your input argument, (b) what accuracy you need.

Comment: Now [ES6 provides this natively](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33591845/1090562).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [here](http://www.musicdsp.org/showone.php?id=238).

```
function rational_tanh(x)
{
    if( x < -3 )
        return -1;
    else if( x > 3 )
        return 1;
    else
        return x * ( 27 + x * x ) / ( 27 + 9 * x * x );
}
```

> This is a rational function to
>   approximate a tanh-like soft clipper.
>   It is based on the pade-approximation
>   of the tanh function with tweaked
>   coefficients.
>
> The function is in the range x=-3..3
>   and outputs the range y=-1..1. Beyond
>   this range the output must be clamped
>   to -1..1.
>
> The first to derivatives of the
>   function vanish at -3 and 3, so the
>   transition to the hard clipped region
>   is C2-continuous.

The Padé approximation is magnitudes better than the Taylor expansion. The clamping may also be an issue (depending on your range).

Comment: Great! What if I have an arbitrary range? Simply scaling the coefficents would be right? (eg: range [-1,1] -> return x * ( 9 + x * x ) / ( 9 + 3 * x * x ))

Comment: I don't think so. From what I understand, 3 was chosen because the first two derivatives vanish at -3 and 3 (remember that we're only using the first 3 elements from the approximation). I don't think scaling the coefficients will give the desired result.

Comment: @janesconference, I just graphed it to double-check and yeah, you don't want to do that :)

Comment: @janesconference for outer range coefs use taylor

Comment: Plotted (without clips at 3) http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiJ4KigyNyt4KngpLygyNys5KngqeCkiLCJjb2xvciI6IiNFODEwMTAifSx7InR5cGUiOjEwMDAsIndpbmRvdyI6WyItNi40OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTYiLCI2LjQ5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5NiIsIi0zLjk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5NzMiLCIzLjk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5NzMiXSwic2l6ZSI6WzE3NDgsNzk4XSwiYmdjb2xvciI6IiMwMDAwMDAiLCJheGVzY29sb3IiOiIjRkZGRkZGIiwiZ3JpZGNvbG9yIjoiIzAwMDAwMCJ9XQ--

Answer (score 6):

You could do this and [cut your performance time in half](http://jsperf.com/tanh-showdown):

```
function tanh(arg) {
    var pos = Math.exp(arg);
    var neg = Math.exp(-arg);
    return (pos - neg) / (pos + neg);
}
```

Comment: in ff4, the test was 41% slower for your solution :(

Comment: @janesconference: Whoa! I see that too in ff4 - I saw the performance boost using Chrome.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure of how big the performance increase will be, but

```
(exp(x) - exp(-x))/(exp(x) + exp(-x)) = (exp(2x) - 1)/(exp(2x) + 1)
```

You'll cut the number of `exp`s in half.

Answer (score 2):

For an accurate answer using fewer `Math.exp()`s, you can use the relationship between tanh and the [logistic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function). `Tanh(x)` is exactly `2 * logistic(2 * x) - 1`, and expanding out the logistic function, you get:

```
  function one_exp_tanh(x){
      return 2.0 / (1.0 + exp(-2.0 * x)) - 1.0;
  }
```

I don't know whether that is faster in javascript though.

Answer (score 2):

ES6 provides this method and many other trig functions natively:

- `Math.sinh` – hyperbolic sine of a number
- `Math.cosh` – hyperbolic cosine of a number
- `Math.tanh` – hyperbolic tangent of a number
- `Math.asinh` – hyperbolic arc-sine of a number
- `Math.acosh` – hyperbolic arc-cosine of a number
- `Math.atanh` – hyperbolic arc-tangent of a number
- `Math.hypot` – square root of the sum of squares

most probably it would be faster than most of JS alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

You could always cut the formula off at a certain number level of accuracy.

```
function tanh (x) {
    return arg - (x * x * x / 3) + (2 * x * x * x * x * x / 15);
}
```

Comment: The taylor expansion's accuracy is [pretty bad](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+expansion+tanh) though.

Comment: Agreed. It's a ton faster, but it really does depend.

Comment: arg is x, I suppose?
This is very useful. Could you point me to a general rule to cut the formula to an arbitrary level of accuracy?

Comment: Yes, sorry. `x` is `arg`. The general Taylor expansion is http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tanh.

Answer (score 1):

this is my answer to this problem

```
function tanh(x){
     var e = Math.exp(2*x)
     return (e-1)/(e+1)
}

Math.constructor.prototype.tanh=tanh;
document.write(Math.tanh(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling that function on chrome takes less than three times of what it takes to call an empty `function f(){}` so I think that you are not going to gain much with any rewriting.

The problem is the function overhead, not the formula. May be inlining it could save something more interesting...

### EDIT

To make the test what I did was just opening a console in Chrome (ctrl-shift-C) and created a timing function with

```
timeit = function(f) {
     var start=(new Date).getTime();
     for (var i=0; i<100000; i++)
         f(1);
     return (new Date).getTime() - start;
}
```

and then tested it with `function(){}` and with your function.

It turns out however that this kind of test is **very** unreliable. I even got absurd results with `timeit(f1)` reporting 200 and `timeit(f2)` reporting 120 (quite a difference) but `f1` and `f2` were indeed two variables linked to the same function object. Also there was a difference between `timeit(f)` and `timeit(function(x){ return Math.cos(x); })` even when `f` was exactly that function.

May be there is an explanation because of how V8 and the javascript console interact but I don't know what it is.

Also with FF4 this approach gives very unreliable results...

Comment: I'm gonna try that. By the way, how did you profile that? (I'm on ff4 and I do the profiling with firebug)